# number of edges in $N$ cube

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, education, mathematical-physics

If the number of edges in an $n$-cube (also denoted as $Q_n$) is $k$, what is the
number of edges in an $(n+1)$-cube (denoted as $Q_{n+1}$)? Express your answer in
terms of $k$ and $n$.

How can I solve this problem? I am thinking about use handshaking theorem to solve this one but still do not know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can take that the vertices of a $n$-cube can be labeled by bit strings of length $n$, from $00...0$ to $11...1$, so that two vertices are connected if and only if their corresponding strings differ exactly in one bit. This will simplify the answer significantly.
(These numbers are actually coordinates in a system with its origin at one chosen vertex and the coordinate axes going along the edges from this vertex. Example: a $2$-cube = square:
$\begin{matrix}00 & 01\\ 
10 & 11
\end{matrix}$.
Note that the edges follow the above mentioned rule.)

---

We can see easily that the number of vertices are $\Rightarrow$ vertices$_n =2^n$. It follows from the above that we can consider it as a n-regular graph of order $2^n$. However, if we just multiplied the number of vertices by the degree, we would count every edge twice. Hence, taking one half of this, we have edges$_n$ =vertices$_n\times$ n $\times \frac{1}{2}$. Here $n$ is the degree. So we have edges$_{n} = n\times 2^{n-1}$.

---

Thus, we have edges$_{n+1} = (n+1)\times 2^n =\frac{2(n+1)}{n}$edges$_{n}$. Hope it helps as in the last answer I multiplied by one degree less, but the idea was the same as intended.

Answer (score 0):

(n+1)-cube consists of two n-cubes and a set of additional edges connecting corresponding vertices of the two cubes. (Like 3-d cube is two squares one above the other, and 4 edges connecting corresponding vertices of these squares).

So, $$edges_{n+1} = 2 * edges_n + 2^n$$

Comment: but why the question ask answer un term of k and n? I don't get it.

Comment: Question does look a little bit strange. It's easy to calculate the required number of edges as a function of $n$ only. But given are $n$ and $k$. One of possible ways to express the answer in terms of $n$ and $k$ would be: $2 * k + 2^n$.